# Abort called error in a program of stack operation when providing a huge input

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl

```
//Stack Operation
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
vector<int> stack;
vector<int>::iterator it;
int maxptr=-1;
it=stack.begin();
int n;
cin>>n;
for(int i=0,q,x,c=0,count;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>q;
    if(q==1)
    {
        cin>>x;
        stack.push_back(x);
        if(x>c)
        {
            count=maxptr;
            maxptr=stack.size()-1;
            c=x;
        }
    }
    else if(q==2)
    {
        if(stack.back()==stack.at(maxptr))
        {
            maxptr=count;
        }
        stack.pop_back();
        if(maxptr==-1)
        {
            c=0;
        }
        else if(stack.size()==0)
        {
            c=0;
        }
        else
        {
            c=stack.at(maxptr);
        }
    }
    else if(q==3)
    {
        cout<<stack.at(maxptr)<<endl;
    }        
  }
}
```

The above code is basic stack program which perform 3 queries. 
Query 1: Push the element in the stack.
Query 2: Pop the topmost element from the stack.
Query 3: find the maximum element in the stack from the elements that are currently present in the stack.
I have used vectors to implement the code but the problem is that is giving abort called error for big inputs like [Input Test Case 1](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/14717/input05.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1523215262&Signature=VrFUOH4rSYCxLhH8kXAC1BkwYcM%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) and [Input Test Case 2](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/14717/input06.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1523215322&Signature=IWEuhcqN4WidKrT6O6lH3fEud%2Bk%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain).

Comment: What do you need iterator `it` for?

Comment: Please don't link to external sites. Post everything relevant *in* the question.

Comment: I was thinking of using it for maxptr but i didn't use it.

Comment: those are the inputs at which the code fails and those are quite large, that's why i didnt include them in that question.

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi -- That first set of input is not large at all and is not "huge input".  You just have a basic bug in your program.  "Huge input" would be in the millions or at the very least, hundreds of thousands of data points, not a few hundred.

Comment: Can you please explain me the bug?

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi -- A little advice -- it isn't a good idea to post a program, see that it doesn't work, and the first thing is to get on stackoverflow and ask someone to debug the program for you.  It doesn't work that way.  Debugging programs is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  Writing perfect programs in one shot isn't how programs are developed -- everyone produces programs with bugs, and learning how to fix those bugs is a mandatory skill, not voluntary.

Comment: @ShantanuDwivedi And [here is your program](https://ideone.com/AyNOaf) with the "huge input".  See the error at the very bottom of the output?  You have an out-of-range error trying to compare the third item in a vector that has only a size of 2 entries.  Also, the program did not stop with an "abort".  It was a `std::out_of_range` exception being thrown due to the good debugging usage of `at()` in your program.  So you had this all set up for self-debugging, but for some reason failed to take advantage of the tools given to you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i know that but i have worked on this code for almost 3-4 days and i'm getting nowhere, so i was asking for advice on how should i tackle this problem.

Comment: Start with the error given.  One of those `at()` calls threw that exception.  Find out which one and figure out why you're accessing elements out-of-bounds.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you for your advice. I appreciate that. I knew the exception you mentioned and I spent enough time debugging it. What I could really use was more helpful ways of debugging it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by using two stacks and by doing a little modification in code.
It will pass all the test cases.

```
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdio>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    vector<int> stack;
    vector<int> maxele;
    int maxptr=-1;
    int n,ct;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0,q,x,c=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>q;
        if(q==1)
        {
            cin>>x;
            stack.push_back(x);
            if(x>=c)
            {
                maxele.push_back(x);
                maxptr=maxele.size()-1;
                c=x;
            }
        }
        else if(q==2)
        {
            if(stack.back()==maxele.back())
            {
                stack.pop_back();
                maxele.pop_back();
                maxptr=maxele.size()-1;
            }
            else 
            {
                stack.pop_back();
            }
            if(maxptr==-1)
            {
                c=0;
            }
            else if(stack.size()==0)
            {
                c=0;
            }
            else
            {
                c=maxele.at(maxptr);
            }
        }
        else if(q==3)
        {
            cout<<maxele.at(maxptr)<<endl;
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The abort called error in this code arises due to a boundary case i.e. if two 
same elements are inserted one after the other then due to the condition in query 1 i.e. if you will execute this condition "if(x>c)" on two same elements then it will not let maxptr update as "c=x" the condition "if(x>c)" will become false.